# Array transpose and corresponding assembly code

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, reverse-engineering, x86-64

C code:

```
void transpose (long A[M][M]) {
    long i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i ++)
        for (j = 0; j < i; j ++) {
            long t = A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = A[j][i];
            A[j][i] = t;
        }
}
```

Corresponding assembly code based on `-O1` optimization for INNER loop:

```
.L6:
    movq   (%rdx), %rcx  //
    movq   (%rax), %rsi
    movq   %rsi, (%rdx)
    movq   %rcx, (%rax)
    addq   $8, %rdx
    addq   $120, %rax
    cmpq   %rdi, %rax
    jne    .L6
```

My understanding of assembly code:

```
1.  movq (%rdx), %rcx
      int *rdx = ?
      int rcx = *rdx  

2.  movq (%rax), %rsi
      int *rax = ?
      int rsi = *rax  

3.  movq %rsi, (%rdx)
      *rdx = rsi = *rax

4.  movq %rcx, (%rax)
      *rax = rcx = *rdi

5.  addq $8, %rdx
      rdx +=8

6.  addq $120, %rax
      rax += 120

7.  cmpq %rdi, %rax
    jne .L6
      int rdi = ?
      if (rdi != rax) jump to L6
```

takeaways:

- `rdx` increments by 8.
- `rdx` is like `j` in C code.
- Each row is 120 bytes long in array.
- outside of `for` loop `rdx` is probably initialized at `0`.
- I still dont get exactly what `rax` is returning.

Questions:

1. Which register holds a pointer to array element `A[i][j]`?
2. Which register holds a pointer to array element `A[j][i]`?
3. What is the value of `M`?

My thinking:

1. `rdx`. `rdx` always goes up by 8, so it goes through the entire row.
2. `rsi` maybe??? `rsi` is set to hold return value and I think return value is the element `A[j][i]`
3. `120 / 8 = 15`

Any confirmation of my answer or rejection would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't a spectacular question, but I can't see how it's too broad, being about the analysis of a specific assembly fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements are `long`s (8  bytes long), and you're examining the inner loop (on `j`), so:

```
rdx +=8
```

means `rdx` is clearly pointing to `A[i][j]`.

```
rax += 120
```

means `rax` is pointing to `A[j][i]`.

`M` equals to 15 as a row is 120 bytes long (distance in bytes in between `A[j][i]` and `A[j+1][i]`), and each `long` is 8 bytes long (distance in between `A[i][j]` and `A[i][j+1]`).

Comment: I get it now. I lost focus on the inner loop and was thinking outside it.